# Time indicator HTML CSS AND JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple HTML AND CSS indicator i want change % of time class height according to these rules:

**08:00 AM is 0%**

**17:25 is 100%** after 17:25 indicator holds 100% till comes 8:00 AM

**My canvas size not always is 550px but it always is `55*myArray.length` (55 is 55 minutes )**

I dont know how to do JavaScript part.

here is my simple indicator

```css
.canvas{
    height: 550px; /* My canvas max size not always is 550px but it allways is 55*myArray.length (55 is 55minutes ) */
    width:100%;
}
.timeIndicator
{
width: 10px;
height:100%;
background: #B57C7C;    
}
.time /**/
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 55%; /*I want to change this parameter */
    background: #B50B0B;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
<div class="timeIndicator">
    <div class="time">
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zs7xjxo6/

Comment: How do you know you can't do the javascript part ? What didn't work when you tried and what errors did you get ?

Comment: @Billy is right. There is no effort on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will return the correct percentage ratio. You may call this function in an interval or use it with jQuery.

```js
var myArrayLength = 10; //let say your array length is 10
document.getElementById('canvas').style.height = 55 * myArrayLength + 'px';
//function below should return the right percentage
function getPercentage() {
    d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = d.getMinutes(),
    s = h * 3600 + m * 60 + d.getSeconds();
    if (s >= 28800 && s <= 62700)
        return (s - 28800) / 339 + '%';
    else
        return '100%';
}
//usage
document.getElementById('time').style.height = getPercentage();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width:100%
}
#timeIndicator {
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height:100%;
    background: #B57C7C
}
#time {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0px;
    background: #B50B0B
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="timeIndicator">
        <div id="time"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```